# Should Navigator be used in tandem with a CupertinoTabBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-layout

I'm learning flutter and starting with a simple 2 tab, bottom navigation bar app (specifically Cupertino based). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PdUaidHc-E) does a decent job of explaining the fundamentals but I am missing something.

The example provided in the video suggests that when you tap on a `BottomNavigationBarItem`, you don't actually *navigate* to a new screen, you simply *re-render* the widgets on the existing screen. The video only invokes `Navigator` after he constructs a button widget in the page container.

Is a `BottomNavigationBarItem` in a `CupertinoTabBar` supposed to invoke `Navigator`? Or am I misunderstanding the use case of `CupertinoTabBar` entirely?

Here is my example code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_solid),
          ), 
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return new Container(
                color: Colors.red
             ); break;
          case 1:
            return new Container(
                color: Colors.white
             ); break;
          default: {
            return new Container(
                color: Colors.white
             );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how I would alter the `switch` to invoke `Navigator` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the pattern that seems to be correct is:

The `CupertinoTabBar` indices / screens which are navigated to via `BottomNavigationBarItem` are really just `CupertinoPageScaffold` widgets. Then within those `CupertinoPageScaffold` screens, you can use the `Navigator` methods to navigate to *other* routes / screens.

The main reason why this makes sense is each index / screen maintains its own navigation stack so you can be on screen (index) 1, navigate a few pages, go to index 0 and back and your navigation stack state is preserved.

It took me a few times reading the [documentation on CupertinoTabScaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold-class.html) to drill it in to my brain but it makes sense.

Let me know if I'm wrong on this.